# Proof If $A_{2x2}$ and $\lambda$ real number then $|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have this problem :

Proof If $A_{2x2}$ and $\lambda$ real number then $|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|$

This is what I did :

I took an arbitrary $A$

$$
   A=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{11} & a_{12} \\
   a_{21} & a_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right)
$$

Now I try to proof $|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|$.

Lets start with $|\lambda I-A|$.

$$|\lambda I-A| =\\ det
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda-a_{11} & -a_{12} \\
   -a_{21} & \lambda-a_{22} \\
  \end{array} } \right)=\\ 
(\lambda-a_{11})(\lambda-a_{22})-(a_{12})(a_{21})=\\ -\lambda(a_{11}a_{22})-(a_{12}a_{21})
$$

Now this : $\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|$.

$$\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|=\\ \lambda^2-\lambda a_{11}-\lambda a_{22}+a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=\\ \lambda^2-\lambda (a_{11}+a{22})+a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}
$$

But that doesn't proof that $|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^2-(\operatorname{tr}A) \lambda+|A|$

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Subtract the two terms and see if the result is zero.

Comment: It does prove it since multiplying out $(\lambda-a_{11})(\lambda-a_{22}) - a_{12}a_{21}$ gives us $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a_{11}+a_{22}) + a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}$ which is exactly what you are trying to show. The mistake above is in $(\lambda-a_{11})(\lambda-a_{22}) - (a_{12})(a_{21}) = -\lambda(a_{11}a_{22}) - a_{12}a_{21}$ which is wrong.

Comment: @Winther Oh, actually I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Comment: I once told a student the analogous calculation for 3 by 3 matrices, he said "why didn't you tell us that?!" Easier than putting in the $\lambda$ and doing a determinant with symbols. On the other hand, not worth worrying about for 4 by 4 or bigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a mistake in the first calculation. $\lambda I - A$ means
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda - a_{11} & -a_{12}\\-a_{21} & \lambda - a_{22}\end{array}\right];$$
the $\lambda$ doesn't appear in every term, only the diagonal.

Comment: Your right, edited.

Comment: In the same calculation, you may want to double-check your simplification of the value you get for the determinant.